# PowerShell: Odd behavior of Conditional "if" Statement

Tags: powershell, match, behavior, conditional-statements

Take a look at the code below. If I run this with only the 1st "if" statement, I get the desired results. Add the 2nd "if" statement (as shown below) and I don't get the desired results. What is wrong here and why is PowerShell behaving in 2 different ways!

```
$CACHE_OS = ""
$OPERATINGSYSTEM = "WIN832_9200"

if ( $OPERATINGSYSTEM -match "WIN832" ) { $CACHE_OS = "WIN832" } else { $CACHE_OS = $OPERATINGSYSTEM }
if ( $OPERATINGSYSTEM -match "WIN864" ) { $CACHE_OS = "WIN864" } else { $CACHE_OS = $OPERATINGSYSTEM }

$CACHE_OS
```

FYI: formatted conditional statements to one-liners for easier read and explanation above.

Comment: What are your "desired results?"  When I run this I get `$cache_os = 'WIN832_9200'` which seems expected.

Comment: My desired results are "WIN832". This is what happens if you run the code above with only 1 (one) "if" statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  I think you might be misinterpreting how the control flow progresses.

```
$CACHE_OS = ""
$OPERATINGSYSTEM = "WIN832_9200"

if ( $OPERATINGSYSTEM -match "WIN832" )  # true
{
  $CACHE_OS = "WIN832"  # $cache_os set to "WIN832"
}
else
{
  $CACHE_OS = $OPERATINGSYSTEM
}

# at this point $cache_os has a value of "WIN832"

if ( $OPERATINGSYSTEM -match "WIN864" ) # false
{
  $CACHE_OS = "WIN864"
}
else # control goes here
{
  $CACHE_OS = $OPERATINGSYSTEM   # $cache_os is re-assigned, new value is "WIN832_9200"
}

$CACHE_OS  # output the current value ("WIN832_9200")
```

Maybe what you meant is to use an `elseif` statement?

```
$CACHE_OS = ""
$OPERATINGSYSTEM = "WIN832_9200"

if ( $OPERATINGSYSTEM -match "WIN832" )
{
  $CACHE_OS = "WIN832"
}
elseif ( $OPERATINGSYSTEM -match "WIN864")
{
  $CACHE_OS = "WIN864"
}
else
{
  $CACHE_OS = $OPERATINGSYSTEM
}
```

Comment: Ok, time for a big "DUH" moment! Of-course! Sorry, I was working on this code EOD and my brain was hurting. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected. In the first IF, $OPERATINGSYSTEM match "WIN832" so $CACHE_OS is set to "WIN832", as you expect, **the ELSE statement list is not executed**.

In the second IF, $OPERATINGSYSTEM does not match "WIN832", so the IF statement list is skipped and **the ELSE part kicks** in and $CACHE_OS is assigned the value of $OPERATINGSYSTEM, which is "WIN832_9200".